# Something wrong with this question

Tags: discussion, support

Honestly speaking I feel [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1564044/reset-insyde-h20-bios-admin-password) is most detailed (with full of research)question that I have ever asked

I feel it’s not getting deserved attention

1. Maybe because people feel They are aiding theft etc, But the laptop is almost 10 years old , even if someone stole it, they could just sell off the parts (cpu, hard disk drive, Network card) And if you add these together it would be equivalent to resell value of laptop.I’m Damn sure they  wouldn’t bother unlocking bios they would directly replace the CMOS chip and sell/use the laptop.
2. Is there Something that I can do to improve my question?

Comment: It looks very fine to me.

Comment: You asked a difficult question.  You might not get an answer due to it’s difficultly

Comment: Nobody mentioned theft except you... *did* you steal it?

Comment: @MichaelFrank The whole point of bios password is to prevent unauthorised access, so that would be the first thing which would come into some ones mind, also questions similar to mine have theft accusations.

Comment: @Chemist - I will repeat a previous observation.  There has not been a single indication, anyone within the community, believes you have stolen the device.  If by chance I have missed that comment, you should report that comment, as it's not required to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This question presents a problem that is not common, or simple - not many users have had this problem before. Similarly, not many users know how to help.

I remember the question, I personally upvoted it, mainly because of your effort and all the attempts you've made. But I didn't feel like I could add anything to the question/conversation. If I had the knowledge, I would gladly write an answer, or at least write some comments.

I don't think theft is a problem here --- maybe the length of the question averts some users.

But mainly, just don't expect more attention to such complicated problems.